# php : action on form's not working- beginner

Tags: php, forms

I'm beginner to php, so I have a small problem with doing an action when submitting a form

The form is something like that

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="?flag=1"> 
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and the php code - on the same page-

```
<?php

if ($flag) {echo "Helllllllllo";}
?>
```

and it didn't work, I tried to make the action on other page like  `action="otherpage.php?flag=1"`

but also it didn't work
any help pls :) ?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the basic concept of GET and POST. Please read up on those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variables** - variables you see in query string

**[$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) variables** - variables you send with form if `method="post"`

If you just need to check if flag exists do:

```
if(isset($_GET['flag'])){
```

Without [isset](http://php.net/isset) you can get **Undefined Index Notice**

Answer (score 2):

Try use:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['flag']) {echo "Helllllllllo";}
?>
```

Still, your form configured incorrectly. Correct one:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['flag'])) { echo "Helllllllllo ", $_POST['flag']; }
?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="flag" value="1">
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Everything after `?` in URL stored in [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php), almost everything else in [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php) (there are exceptions for files and some other special stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['flag'])) {echo "Helllllllllo";}
?>
```

---

**EDIT**
But the problem is another, you make a post request and make an action in GET try this for your purpose:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action=""> 
  <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="1">
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['flag'])) {echo "Helllllllllo";}
?>
```

In this mode you pass your variable falg with the value 1 to your oage and you can retrieve it with the $_POST

Answer (score 0):

what is `$flag`

```
Try $_SERVER["flag"]


<?php

if ($_SERVER["flag"]) {echo "Helllllllllo";}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You form is wrong, you need to page as action the same page or what else page you want to redirect to and then get the `POST` variable, cast in a variable and use for your `if` condition

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"> 
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="1">
</form>

$flag = $_POST['flag'];

if ($flag == '1') {echo "Helllllllllo";}
```